# Align baseline of two elements

Tags: html, css

I've the following HTML & CSS:

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="width:500px">
  <h1>My Title</h1>
  <span class="float-right">Text on the right border</span>
</div>
```

- How to align the text on the right with the baseline of the h1?
- How to align the text on the right in the middle of the h1 text?

I don't want to do "pixel-rodeo" and adjust the line-height to exactly 17.533 pxiels if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Flexbox like so :)

More reading on Flexbox -> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
div {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-between
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="width:500px">
  <h1>My Title</h1>
  <span class="float-right">Text on the right border</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way without changing the div or the h1?

Comment: If You want to modify these elements, You need to add some CSS to the parent / child. It's a good practice. HTML was unchanged. I only added some CSS properties :)

Comment: I hope it answers your question :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using bootstrap, so if you add the classes `row align-items-center` all children will be vertically centered.
https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-4-vertical-center-1211448a2eff

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="width:500px" class="row align-items-center">
  <h1>My Title</h1>
  <span class="float-right">Text on the right border</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks nice. But it has two downsides: the span is no longer on the right but sticks to the end of the h1. Also it doesn't seem to be aligned "center" but "baseline"?!

Comment: It's not worth using bootstrap only for such change

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea without the use of flexbox:

```css
.text-justify:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
Baseline
<div style="width:500px" class="text-justify">
  <h1 class="d-inline-block ">My Title</h1> 
  <span class="d-inline-block ">Text on the right border</span>
</div>
Middle
<div style="width:500px" class="text-justify">
  <h1 class="d-inline-block align-middle">My Title</h1> 
  <span class="d-inline-block ">Text on the right border</span>
</div>
```

Using flexbox I recommend this solution since you are considering bootstrap:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
Baseline
<div style="width:500px" class="d-flex align-items-baseline">
  <h1 >My Title</h1>
  <span class="ml-auto">Text on the right border</span>
</div>
Middle
<div style="width:500px" class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <h1 >My Title</h1>
  <span class="ml-auto">Text on the right border</span>
</div>
```